# robot_localization estimate drifts for a stationary robot in rviz

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using robot_localization to fuse odometry, imu and gps measurements. However once my robot is spawn in rviz, it starts drifting. The /imu/data output keeps changing and the estimated pose is inaccurate.

My robot_localization configuration is:

```
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find fav)/config/dual_ekf_navsat_transform.yaml"/>
<node name="ekf_se_odom" pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" output="screen" clear_params="true" />
<node name="ekf_se_map" pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" output="screen" clear_params="true">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
</node>
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform" output="screen" clear_params="true">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
    <remap from="gps/fix" to="/navsat/fix" />
    <remap from="imu/data" to="/imu/data" />
</node>
```

and my dual_ekf_navsat_transform.yaml is

```
ekf_se_odom:
  frequency: 100
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: false
  transform_time_offset: 0.5
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_footprint
  world_frame: odom

  odom0: fav_velocity_controller/odom
  odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 true,  true,  true,
                 false, false, true,
                 false, false, false]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false

  imu0: /imu/data
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                true,  true,  false,
                false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                true,  true,  true]
  imu0_nodelay: false
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: false

  use_control: false
  process_noise_covariance: [1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5,   0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.1,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3]

  initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1.0,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1.0,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1.0,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1.0,  0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1.0]

ekf_se_map:
  frequency: 100
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: false
  transform_time_offset: 0.5
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_footprint
  world_frame: map

  odom0: fav_velocity_controller/odom
  odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 true,  true,  true,
                 false, false, true,
                 false, false, false]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false

  odom1: /odometry/gps
  odom1_config: [true,  true,  false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  odom1_queue_size: 10
  odom1_nodelay: true
  odom1_differential: false
  odom1_relative: false

  imu0: /imu/data
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                true,  true,  false,
                false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                true,  true,  true]
  imu0_nodelay: true
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: false
  
  use_control: false
  
  process_noise_covariance: [1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5,   0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.1,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3]

  initial_estimate_covariance: [1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1.0,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1.0,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1.0,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1.0,  0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1.0]


navsat_transform:
  frequency: 100
  delay: 3.0
  magnetic_declination_radians: 3.06  # For lat/long 55.944831, -3.186998
  yaw_offset: 0 #1.570796327  # IMU reads 0 facing magnetic north, not east
  zero_altitude: true
  broadcast_utm_transform: true
  publish_filtered_gps: true
  use_odometry_yaw: false
  wait_for_datum: false
```

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321403/robot_localization-estimate-drifts-for-a-stationary-robot-in-rviz/) by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2019-04-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agurman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40767/agurman/) on 2019-04-20**:
A couple of things, how are you handling your IMU data, is it being passed through a filter such as `imu_filter_madgwick` a node such as this will give you the flexibility to adjust the gain values and alleviate some of that drift. If you are already doing this and cannot get your imu drift any better, the next thing to check would be the hardware layer, is the imu faulty or simply bad? Imu and wheel odometry drift is unavoidable and an ekf will not solve it. I run a dual ekf setup and in my second gps node, i don't fuse imu and wheel odometry, luckily i have a gnss provided heading so this outputs a highly accurate (although still discontinuous) map frame with effectively zero drift.

**Comment by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) on 2019-04-21**:
@agurman Thanks for your response. Can the imu_filter_node be used with libhector_gazebo_ros_gps.so plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please update the question by including sample messages from each sensor input.

So you have jumped in to the deep end. I recommend that you start with a simple configuration (just a single EKF) that fuses just IMU and wheel encoder data, and then build up the complexity from there.

In this case, your issue is very likely the inclusion of acceleration data from the IMU. Try turning that off to start, and see if that helps.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2019-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0